# How to use Toolbar in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I want to use the Toolbar in my app (create with Eclipse IDE) and use this Toolbar on all Activities.

I think this code will be work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<!-- Layout for content is here. This can be a RelativeLayout  -->
```

but i dont have any idea for usage

sorry for bad english, i'm iranian.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Toolbar in each layout.xml of all your Activities.

Just for example:

```xml
<LinearLayout
        ...>

    <Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where are layout.xml's?